# How realize two different windows (no contemporary) in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to create in OpenGL two differents windows but they should appears not together.
I mean: when I execute my code I visualize both of windows contemporarily.
My aim instead is to visualize at the beginning the first window, then the first window should be closed and the second will appear. My pseudocode is the following (this realeses only the two windows together ntemporarily):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    initRendering();
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    //window1=
    glutCreateWindow("First window");

    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene1);
    glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
    cout << "Before inserting 'choice' I want to visualize the first window\n
             After the insert of 'choice' I want to visualize the second window 
             and close the first one !";
    cin >> choice;

    //create the second  window
    //window2 =
    glutCreateWindow("Second Window");

    //define a window position for second window
    glutPositionWindow(540, 40);

    // register callbacks for second window, which is now current
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene2);
    glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two windows?

Comment: Since from an initial figure, after transforming it, I want to visualize the result. The transformation must depend on the input 'choice' and so I need to insert it and then visualize the result.

Comment: What don't you create a button inside the window, then update the window upon pushing the button and show the visualization?

Comment: @KaiserKatze How can I do this? Can you give me a hint in a pseudo code?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with OpenGL - OpenGL does not even have a concept of a "window". Your problem is solely GLUT, and GLUT is very limited, and very outdated. Within the GLUT specification, what you desire can't be implemented, with the extensions modern _freeglut_ implementations offer it can, but honestly, you should not be using GLUT in the first place.